# Key Press on iOS Devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, keyboard, iphone-standalone-web-app

I need to run a function every time a key is pressed. This works fine for computers but on an iOS Device it doesn't seem to register. The html element is

```
<input id="word" type="text" value="" onkeyup="game.check_score()"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This appears to work for me on the iOS Simulator. Have you tried onkeypress or onkeydown?

Comment: They worked in this iOS Simulator but not on an iPad. (iPad 2 iOS 7)

Comment: Try debugging with Safari Web Inspector. Check that the Javascript is actually loaded. Step debug and check the error console. Setup instructions: http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: One thing that might be happening is if you have multiple scripts/plugins triggering at keyup, they might be overriding each other. You want to debug remotely and then check the JavaScript Events tab under Timelines on the debug console